# Assure Spring bean is singleton

Tags: java, spring, singleton, javabeans

How can I assure that a Spring bean is a singleton?

I'd implement the Interfaces [`ApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), [`InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and [`BeanNameAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html).

In [`afterPropertiesSet()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29) I'd call [`isSingleton(String)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#isSingleton%28java.lang.String%29) with the Bean's name.

Is there another way to make sure that a Bean is a singleton?

Because [according to the API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html):

> Note that it is not usually recommended that an object depend on its
>   bean name, as this represents a potentially brittle dependence on
>   external configuration, as well as a possibly unnecessary dependence
>   on a Spring API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i recall correctly, a spring-managed bean will be a singleton by default (for current versions of the spring-library), unless you define the scope to be of type 'prototype'.

Check: [Default scope of spring beans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

Quote:

> The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring

Comment: Yes, and I want to make sure, that this is the case.

Comment: @BernhardV Then you dont have to do anything in particular - its singleton by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it "*the Java way*" with [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) flag:

```
private static final created = new AtomicBoolean();

@PostConstruct
public void ensureSingleInstance() {
    if(created.getAndSet(true)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Trying to create second instance");
    }
}
```

But do you really need such an assertion? Beans have `scope="singleton"` by default...