# Can I programmatically determine if a spring bean is not singleton?

Tags: java, spring, scope

When I get a spring bean (via getBean()), is there any way to verify from java code that the bean has been defined with scope=prototype ?

Spring config:

```
<bean class="foo.Bar" scope="prototype" />
```

Java:sc

```
MyBean bean = springApplicationContext.getBean("MyBean");
```

I could just instantiate it twice and compare the objects, but I'd like to avoid unnecessary object creation. Something like the opposite of this answer would do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125610/156477

Comment: If you need to know, there's a problem with your design.  If you tell us what you are really trying to do, we might be able to suggest better ideas.

Comment: My app can load spring config from 3rd party sources. I want a sanity check on a particular bean that must be scope=prototype.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a API `boolean isPrototype(String name)` in `ApplicationContext` to check it.

Comment: Does this also work for job, and step scoped beans?