# Spring - ensure a bean is a session bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to make sure that a given bean was defined with a session scope.

I know that I can use `ctx.isSingleton()` or `ctx.isPrototype()` where `ctx` is my (Web)ApplicationContext, but, there is no `isSession()`.

If you'd like to know why I'd need something like this, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20126706/295797).

Related : [Can I programmatically determine if a spring bean is not singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15475852/295797)

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
AbstractApplicationContext abstractContext = (AbstractApplicationContext) context;
BeanFactory = beanFactory = abstractContext.getBeanFactory();

BeanDefinition beanDefinition = ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).
                                    getBeanDefinition("beanName");
boolean isSessionScope = "session".equals(beanDefinition.getScope());
```

I am not 100% sure if beanDefinition.getScope() returns "session" or "session_scope" or something similar, but I think that should be no problem for you to find the right String.

---

An alternate way to get the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` would be getting it by injection or implement the `BeanFactoryAware` Interface.

---

If your Application context is of type `GenericApplicationContext` then you can use the method `GenericApplicationContext.getBeanDefinition(String name)` directly.

Comment: Thanks - This is close - First is that the ApplicationContext interface does not have a getBeanFactory() method, you'll need to cast it to an instance of AbstractApplicationContext.  Another option is to have the bean implement BeanFactoryAware so that a BeanFactory is injected.  Even then, BeanFactory interface does not implement getBeanDefinition, so you'll have to cast it to an instance of DefaultListableBeanFactory (seems sketchy..). If you update your answer I can accept it?